# how to draw infinte in a flowchart

Tags: java, infinite, flowchart

I was learning flowcharts, wanted to show this code in a flowchart, wanted to print infinite times without declaring a counter. please note I haven't declared any counter.

```
for (;;){
        System.out.println("helloworld"); 
    }       }
```

Comment: Seems like you have achieved what you wanted. What is your question?

Comment: how to represent this in a flowchart, don't downvote if you cant understand

Comment: there are certain rules for making a flowchart, like shape of boxes, etc.

Comment: u can use raptor tool to draw a flowchart

Comment: Please have a look at [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on Stack Overflow. Try to research your question, then try some approach(es), then come and ask *specific* question, with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Try to avoid posting unresearched and broad questions that show none of your attempts at all. Flow Charts can be implemented in a number of ways, and every answer may differ from based on opinions.

Comment: I have read that, certain rules are there to make a flow chart, usually in a flow chart containing a loop uses a counter, but in code, you can implement it without using a counter so I was asking about a way to do the same in the flowchart

Comment: Just make an arrow that goes back to where you need it to, without a conditional box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An infinite loop is like any other loop an arrow that goes back to a previous point.

Usually, you still place a condition (rhombus/diamond shape) at the start of the loop as usual, but there is only one outgoing path.